# How to build a light meter program?

Tags: iphone, algorithm, image-processing, camera

Given a live captured image (say, on an iPhone), how to calculate the require exposure time value programmatically based on the apertures, ISOs? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The amount of captured light is proportional to shutterspeed*ISO/aperture.

So if, for instance, your iPhone has choosen f2.8, 1/60s ISO 800, and your camera has the constraints of f4 and ISO 100, the needed shutter speed would be 1/60s*800/2.8*4/100 ≈ 1/5s.